# Change the output path from the cucumber report

Tags: ruby, cucumber, output, report

I have one question about Cucumber and Ruby. I have the cucumber.yml file in my project and I generate the reports according to this line:

**html: --format html --out=reports/relatorio.html**

But I need that every execution of my test create this report in a different folder. I have this path save in a variable. It is possible to do that? Can I overide this configurations from cucumber.yml file somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

**`html: --format html --out=reports/{variablename}/relatorio.html`**

Or:

**`html: --format html --out=reports/${variablename}/relatorio.html`**